# Can't solve issue : "Cannot create index on LOB columns", even with right index columns

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, teradata

**I have a dataframe `df`, which I want to save into Teradata DB.** But I am meeting an issue.

This df is extracted from the open data link : https://equipements.sports.gouv.fr/explore/dataset/data-es/table/

I am using :

```
df.to_sql(
    'df_teradata', 
    schema='my_db_name', 
    if_exists='replace',
    index=False,
    con=connexion)
```

where `connexion` is my connexion to the Teradata Sever (and no problem comes from it in this issue).

I meet the error :

```
 [Teradata Database] [Error 5660] Cannot create index on LOB columns
```

I know that there is also an [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153641/cannot-create-index-on-lob-columns-teradataodbc-teradata-driverteradata-da) on this, and understood that Teradata takes the first column in the table as the PI. **To overcome this, I did** :

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
# df["index"] = df['index'].astype(str)
df.to_sql('df_teradata', schema='my_db_name', if_exists='replace',
    index=True,
    con=connexion)
```

(thus setting `index=True`). But even when changing the type of index from `int` to `str`, I still have the same issue.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

**EDIT :**
I solved the case doing :

```
df = df.assign(index=lambda x: x['index'].astype(int))
df.to_sql(
    'df_teradata', 
    schema='my_db_name', 
    if_exists='replace',
    index=False,
    con=connexion)
```

**BUT** it creates me such a DB in Teradata :

[image: Resulting picture] (each row of each column is a .txt document, and when opening it, appears the value of the content).

Comment: I solved the issue doing : `df = df.assign(index=lambda x: x['index'].astype(int))`. Using `int` format works.

Comment: The .txt document for each column is client (SQL Assistant) behavior. Assuming the columns are defined as VARCHAR then you can use Tools / Options / Data Format to increase the size of values it will attempt to display inline in the grid control vs treating as separate "CLOB" documents (Handle Varchar columns as CLOBs if size >)

Comment: I solved it: I had to specify the type of each columns of my dataframe with `df.dtypes = {col1='str', ..., 'coln'='int'}`, or `dtypes={...}` in the `df.to_sql` function. Thus, I had to change erery column with type `object` into something else such as `int`, `float`, `str`.